# Python Gurobi not able to get optimize solution

Tags: python, gurobi, vehicle-routing

I'm working on a Gurobi optimize question but can't not find the solution I want.
This question is trying to find the best path for picking materials in warehouse.

Here is the current solution.

```
x(0,5,33) 1.0
q(1,33) 2.0
x(1,2,33) 1.0
q(2,33) 2.0
x(2,3,33) 1.0
q(3,33) 2.0
x(3,4,33) 1.0
q(4,33) 2.0
x(4,1,33) 1.0
q(5,33) 2.0
x(5,0,33) 1.0
```

Here is my code.

```
from gurobipy import*

N = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] #Material location in warehosue, 0 is depot
S = [1] #The configuration need to be pick up

#Material list with location n
I, K = multidict({1:11, 2:12, 3:13, 4:42, 5:41})

#Distance between each location
R1 = {(0,1): 3, (0,2): 6, (0,3): 5, (0,4):4, (0,5): 2,\
      (1,2): 3, (1,3): 4, (1,4): 3, (1,5): 3,\
     (2,3): 3, (2,4): 6, (2,5): 4, (3,4): 3, (3,5): 7, (4,5): 6}
R = {}
for i,j in R1:
    R[j,i]=R1[i,j]
    R[i,j]=R1[i,j] #把0,1 -> 1,0

#Capacity
C = 10
#the batch of picking
L = [l for l in range(1,60)]

#BOM list (S:K1,K2,K3,K4,K5) 
BOM = {1:[11,12,13,42,41]}

#Quantity demand of configuration
S, D = multidict({1:2})

#Decision variable
model = Model("Picking path")
x = {}
q = {}
u = {}
for l in L:
    for i in range(len(N)+1):
        q[i,l]=model.addVar(vtype="C", name="q(%s,%s)" %(i,l))
        for j in range(len(N)+1):
            x[i,j,l]=model.addVar(vtype="B", name="x(%s,%s,%s)" %(i,j,l))
for l in L:
    for i in range(len(N)+1):
        u[i,l]=model.addVar(vtype="C", name="u(%s)" %i)

model.update()

#Constraints
BigM = 10**6
for l in L:
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[0,j,l] for j in N if j!=0)*BigM >= quicksum(q[j,l] for j in N), name="A.3")
    model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,0,l] for i in N if i!=0)*BigM >= quicksum(q[j,l] for j in N), name="A.4")
    for j in N:
        model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j,l] for i in N if i!=j)\
                       -quicksum(x[j,v,l] for v in N if v!=j)==0, name="A.2")
        model.addConstr(quicksum(x[i,j,l] for i in N if i!=j)*BigM >= q[j,l], name="A.5")
        model.addConstr(q[j,l] <= C, name="A.6")
            
for i in range(1,len(N)):
    for s in S:
        for k in K:
            model.addConstr(quicksum(q[i,l] for l in L)\
                            ==quicksum(D[s] for s in BOM if K[i] in BOM[s]), name="A.7")
                
#subtour
for l in L:
    model.addConstr(u[0,l]==0)
    for i in range(len(N)+1):
        for j in N:
            if i!=j:
                model.addConstr(u[i,l]-u[j,l] + (len(N)+1)*x[i,j,l] <= (len(N)+1), name="A.8")


#Objective
model.setObjective(quicksum(R[i,j]*x[i,j,l] for i in N for j in N for l in L if i!=j), GRB.MINIMIZE)

model.optimize()
```

I would like to have the solution go as 0-5 locations-0 as 1 big circle.
But now it's two circel (0-5-0 / 1-2-3-4-1), as below.

How can I modify the code to solve this issue?